# Creating an if statement where a coordinate must be in between a set of coordinates in Swift

Tags: swift, if-statement

I am currently in the process of writing a PONG game in Swift. I have gotten to the point where I am trying to get the game ball to rebound off the player's paddle. I am having trouble creating an if statement using the coordinates of the player's paddle. I will write in pseudo code what I mean.

```
If the game ball is in between the right most x coordinate of the player paddle and the right most coordinate of the player paddle and the y value of the game ball is the same as the y value of the player paddle {

Do this code

}
```

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
if GameBall.center.x <= PlayerPaddle.center.x + 50 && GameBall.center.x >= PlayerPaddle.center.x - 50 && GameBall.center.y - 5 == PlayerPaddle.center.y + 15 {
            if GameBallDirection == "W" {
                GameBallDirection = "E"
            }
```

However this does not work. Is there a way to write a condition which requires the Game Ball to be within the left and right most x coordinates of the player paddle? I know this may seem vague but I have tried to explain it as best as possible and any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Just 2 notes: A) don't use upper case for your instances as first char. B) use a class Coordinates that can be compared.

Comment: What's wrong with using upper case for the first char? Does using upper/lower case not just come down to personal preference?

Comment: It helps to follow standards when naming things so that everyone can more easily understand code. If you work in a team in future or get someone else to help with your code life will be a lot easier if there is a common standard to work to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `x` part looks ok. The `y` part:

```
GameBall.center.y - 5 == PlayerPaddle.center.y + 15
```

is looking for float equality, which will basically never be true. You should be using `>=` instead, to check if the ball has reached or passed the start of the paddle.

Without seeing all your code I can't be sure, but you may also need to consider which side of the screen the paddle is at for `>=` or `<=` usage...

Comment: Have you considered using SpriteKit? The included physics engine (much simpler and more straight forward than it sounds) and automatic collision detection can make much of this coordinate-induced headache a thing of the past.

Comment: @Magnas No I haven't tried using SpriteKit, I may try look in to it if I cannot figure anything out with what I am doing now. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Wain lovely thanks, I did not previously consider using >/< as if the GameBall goes past PlayerPaddle, the opposition is supposed to gain a point. However, I was able to workaround it! Thanks a lot!!